# Como é o funcionamente do Fallback da Polly?

Tags: c#, terminologia, polly, resiliência

Estou tentando entende como funciona [Fallback da Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly), mas não estou conseguindo fazer a implementação corretamente.

Pelo que entendi ele executa outra ação caso a primeira falhe, mas não é isso que esta acontecendo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CircuitBreakingPolly
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static int n1 = 2;
        public static int n2 = 0;
        public static DateTime programStartTime;
        private static List<Produtos> produtos = new List<Produtos>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pmp = new PoliticasManipulacaoPolly();
            Task result = pmp.ExecuteFallback(() => CallTask(), () => CallTask2());

            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public async static Task CallTask()
        {
            if (DateTime.Now < programStartTime.AddSeconds(10))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task falhou.");
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Console.WriteLine("Task completa.");
        }

        public async static Task CallTask2()
        {
            if (DateTime.Now < programStartTime.AddSeconds(10))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task falhou.");
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Console.WriteLine("Task completa.");
        }
    }
}
```

Meu método;

```
public Task ExecuteFallback(Func<Task> action, Func<Task> fallbackAction)
{
    Program.programStartTime = DateTime.Now;
    Task result = null;

    try
    {
       var esult2 = Policy.Handle<Exception>()
            .Fallback(() => fallbackAction(), onFallback: (exception, context) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                //Log(exception);
                throw exception;
            })
            .Execute(action);

    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        //Log(ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        //Log(ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Na chamada do meu primeiro método esta simulando corretamente, mas não é chamado o segundo método após o erro do primeiro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Estava montando de uma forma errada :( claro, o que realmente eu precisava era passar a action para o método Fallback da POLLY sem precisa fazer mais nada, da forma que estava implementada não estava dando erro, mas não erra a forma de chama uma nova action para se executada e sim uma forma de gravar logs, essa forma também já foi marcada como Obsolete.

> Obsolete("This overload is deprecated and will be removed in a future
>   release. Prefer the overload in which both fallbackAction and
>   onFallback take a Context input parameter.")]

Existe o [PolicyWrap](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) que possibilita executar mais de uma politica.

A solução encontrada;

```
public Task ExecuteFallbackWrap(Func<Task> action, Func<Task> fallbackAction)
{
    Program.programStartTime = DateTime.Now;
    Task result = null;

    var politicaWithFallback = Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .Fallback(() => fallbackAction());

    var politicaRetry = Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .Retry(2);
    try
    {
        result = politicaWithFallback.Execute(action);

        // ou combinado
        var mixedPolicy = Policy.Wrap(politicaWithFallback, politicaRetry).Execute(action);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        Log(ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```