# Pra que serve a programação reativa?

Tags: paradigma-de-programação, programação-reativa

Eu já li [O que é Reactive Programming (Programação Reativa)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55332/101). A resposta parece boa, mas é teórica. Entendi o que é, mas com aquilo não sei o que fazer.

Onde deve ser usada?

Tem um exemplo simples?

Qual é o mecanismo concreto usado para isto funcionar? Concreto até onde pode ser, entendo que em programação tudo é abstração a não ser os elétrons excitados :)

Só funciona entre agentes locais ou um deles pode ser remoto? É por causa da internet?

Só funciona se for algo "inteligente, interligada em paralelo, não linear? Se for, o que é esse inteligente?

Aparentemente tem que ter robustez para ser classificada assim? Precisa rodar em vários servidores? Ou é uma opção?

É um paradigma? É um *framework*? Posso usar em .NET?

Comment: Elétrons excitados  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: Essa pergunta é muito boa, e difícil de entra em detalhes devido a complexidade ela envolve os design patterns, como descrito no final da resposta da outra pergunta. Um exemplo e a biblioteca da [Polly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220111/como-%C3%A9-o-funcionamente-do-fallback-da-polly) que torna a aplicação mais  Resiliente. Muitas outras tecnologias devem ser envolvidas para se ter uma Programação Reativa.

Comment: Em um comentário do link que você postou, foi indicado o seguinte link como o melhor material já lido pelo usuário: https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor

Comment: @bigown Achei sua pergunta interessante pois também não sabia o que era ao certo, dai fui procurar na net e achei essa resposta que achei interessante! https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55332/o-que-%C3%A9-reactive-programming-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-reativa

Comment: @Perozzo parece sensacional, só por isso já valeu a pergunta.

Comment: @miltoncamara está na pergunta.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza aí fica a seu critério, eu gostaria de ver a resposta.

Comment: @bigown agora entendi que você fez um link com a resposta que você leu rs.

Comment: @bigown sensacional mesmo, nunca tinha lido sobre. Comecei a ler agora e achei muito interessante.

Comment: ta dando vontade de por uma oferenda nessa pergunta para ver se aparece um aventureiro que entenda do assunto.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza aí é com você. A sua está boa, mas ainda seria legal alguma outra. Depois quero fazer outras sobre o assunto. Eu postei no grupo de MVP e tenho certeza que tem alguém lá que daria uma ótima resposta, mas no momento só peguei um ou outro que queria reclamar em vez de ajudar, certamente tem outros entre os mais de 100 com atitude mais positiva, quem sabe um deles responda.

Comment: Segue referência: A discussão abaixo está bem rica e vai agregar bem ao tema. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming

Comment: Voce devia ter aberto um bounty na pergunta antiga. A sua pergunta é uma pergunta duplicada.

Comment: @BrunoCosta como pode ser duplicada se o que eu estou perguntando é tudo diferente, até mostro que li aquele. Só porque o assunto é o mesmo não é a mesma. Eu posso por uma nessa porque até agora tem respostas boas, mas que ainda não respondem 100%.

Comment: Eu vejo essa tal "programação reativa" como um excelente uso do princípio do design pattern Observer. Já cansei de implementar isso na mão nas mais diversas plataformas do java (desktop, ee, android ...) e confesso que sentia falta de algo mais padronizado. RxJava caiu muito bem -> https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Comment: Já achou sua resposta ?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza acho que não, vou aguardar um pouco, vou tentar trazer alguém que responda

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Pra que serve a programação reativa?**

A programação reativa vem nos salvar em situações onde o fluxo normal seria parado por um erro [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] ou por um tempo de resposta demorado devido a quantidade de núcleos estáticos entre outras especificações envolvidas nos seus pilares. Resumindo, para entender para que serve, é necessário entender seus pilares.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Aqui tem um bom resumo deles](https://blog.andrefaria.com/migrando-uma-aplicacao-para-arquitetura-reativa).

**Resiliente**: Reage às falhas; aplicações reagem e se recuperam de
falhas de software, hardware e de conectividade;

Ou seja, na ocorrência de uma falha, a aplicação teria a inteligência de realizar uma ação sem a intervenção do usuário. Um cenário seria a chamada de um serviço remoto: imagine que em uma determinada chamada a esse serviço não responda, logo uma exceção de *time out* será lançada em um cenário normal. Já na programação reativa, uma ação seria tomada para que de alguma forma a falha seja corrigida, por exemplo: aguarde x minutos e tente novamente.

**Message Driven**; Uma arquitetura orientada por mensagens é a base das aplicações reativas. Um aplicativo orientado por mensagem pode ser conduzido por eventos, com base em ator ou uma combinação dos dois.

Um sistema baseado em eventos é baseado em eventos que são monitorados por zero ou mais observadores. Isso é diferente da programação não reativa, porque o chamador não precisa bloquear a espera de uma resposta da rotina invocada. Os eventos não são direcionados para um endereço específico, mas sim são vistos (ou ouvidos).

A concorrência baseada em ator é uma extensão da arquitetura de passagem de mensagens, onde as mensagens são direcionadas para um destinatário, que passa a ser um ator. As mensagens podem atravessar limites de thread ou serem passadas para a caixa de correio de outro ator em um servidor físico diferente. Isso permite a elasticidade - escalando a demanda - à medida que os atores podem ser distribuídos pela rede, ainda assim se comunicam entre si como se todos estivessem compartilhando a mesma JVM.

A principal diferença entre mensagens e eventos é que as mensagens são direcionadas enquanto os eventos acontecem. As mensagens têm um destino claro, enquanto os eventos podem ser observados por zero ou mais observadores.

**Responsivo:** Um sistema responsivo é rápido para reagir a todos os usuários *(sob condições boas ou não)* para garantir uma experiência rica e “tempo real” de usuário consistentemente positiva.

A rapidez e a experiência positiva do usuário em várias condições, como a falha de um sistema externo ou uma onda de tráfego, depende dos dois traços de uma aplicação Reativa: resiliência e escalabilidade. Uma arquitetura orientada por mensagens fornece a base geral para um sistema responsivo.

Por que uma arquitetura orientada por mensagens é tão importante para a capacidade de resposta?

O mundo é assíncrono. Aqui está um exemplo: você está prestes a preparar um café, mas você percebe que está sem creme e açúcar.

Uma possível abordagem seria:

- Comece a preparar o café.
- Vá para a loja enquanto o café está se preparando.
- Compre creme e o açúcar.
- Volte para casa.
- Beba café imediatamente.
- Aproveite a vida.

Outra possível abordagem:

- Vá para a loja.
- Compre creme e açúcar.
- Volte para casa.
- Comece a preparar o café.
- Observe com paciência o café à medida que ele é feito.
- Experimente o café.
- Aproveite a vida.

Como você pode ver claramente, uma arquitetura orientada por mensagem fornece um limite assíncrono que o desacoplará da hora e do espaço.

**Elástico:** Reage à demanda/carga: aplicações podem fazer uso de múltiplos núcleos e múltiplos servidores;

Um sistema escalável é facilmente atualizado sob demanda para garantir a capacidade de resposta em várias condições de carga.

O [Akka. Net](https://getakka.net/articles/concepts/supervision.html) aborda muito bem esses assuntos em uma forma de autor, onde, no caso de um aumento espontâneo de acesso a um servidor, seu gerenciamento é quase de forma automática ou em caso de alguma falha em um dos autores uma decisão é tomada pelo autor que fez a chamada.

[Aqui](https://getakka.net/articles/concepts/supervision.html) tem uma boa demonstração do uso de autor do Akka.

**Agora as perguntas.**

> Onde deve ser usada?

O cenário mais utilizado que tenho visto é em aplicação com grandes volumes de chamadas e de mudanças repentinas de acessos, mas nada impede de ser usada em qualquer outro sistema.

> Tem um exemplo simples?

No site do [akka.net](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/receive-actor-api.html) são abordados vários conceitos de como implementar.

> Qual é o mecanismo concreto usado para isto funcionar? Concreto até
> onde pode ser, entendo que em programação tudo é abstração a não ser
> os elétrons excitados :)

Conforme mencionado na outra resposta. Um dos mecanismos é o Observer, o [stream do Akka.net](https://getakka.net/articles/streams/quickstart.html) e o [Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)), levam a mesma abordagem, embora mesmo assim não vejo a abordagem completa.

No akka.net um dos conceitos usado é o de autores onde um acompanhamento sobre as atividades de uma aplicação e monitorada por um [supervisor](https://getakka.net/articles/concepts/supervision.html). Cada subordinado repassa a seu supervisor o que esta acontecendo a si. Na ocorrência de uma falha, uma resposta é repassada para o supervisor e uma ação é tomada de acordo com a falha.

> Só funciona entre agentes locais ou um deles pode ser remoto? É por
> causa da internet?

Engloba os dois cenários, tanto pode ser aplicado em agente locais como remoto, (É por causa da internet), muitas mudanças ocorrem pela bendita internet (save internet) e umas delas é sim programação reativa.

> Aparentemente tem que ter robustez para ser classificada assim?
> Precisa rodar em vários servidores? Ou é uma opção?

Não, poder ser uma aplicação simples.

> É um paradigma? É um framework? Posso usar em .NET?

São padrões que podem ser implementados com .NET sim, como falado anteriormente sobre as bibliotecas *POLLY.NET, AKKA.NET.*  o Akka pode ser usando em C#, Java entre outras.

**Resumindo;**
Programação reativa permite aplicações mais disponíveis, mais rápidas e mais confiáveis, capazes de se auto recuperarem e se gerenciarem.

Com a ajuda de ferramentas como o ***Akka, Polly, WebSockets, DynamoDB, EC2, Autoscaling e Serviços de Mensagens (SQS, SNS, SWF),*** podemos construir aplicações reativas com esforço relativamente baixo.

Answer (score 33):

Muitas pessoas misturam os termos e conceitos de **programação reativa** e de **sistemas reativos**, talvez devido ao [Reactive Manifesto](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/). Em janeiro de 2017, a Lightbend [publicou um whitepaper](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/white-paper-understanding-reactive-programming-vs-reactive-systems) (em inglês) que  explica os dois conceitos e suas diferenças chave.

Esta resposta se baseia nos conceitos da programação reativa.

---

> Onde deve ser usada?

Pode ser utilizada em vários lugares. Desde uma consulta a um banco de dados "local", passando por monitorar o ponteiro em uma tela, até sistemas distribuídos que lidam com um número grande de requisições por segundo.

---

> Tem um exemplo simples?

Observando o movimento do mouse no Silverlight:

```
var mouseMove = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventArgs>(this, "MouseMove");
mouseMove.ObserveOnDispatcher()
         .Subscribe(args => Debug.WriteLine(args.EventArgs.GetPosition(this)));
```

[fonte](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc8)

---

> Qual é o mecanismo concreto usado para isto funcionar? Concreto até
>   onde pode ser, entendo que em programação tudo é abstração a não ser
>   os elétrons excitados :)

Um dos mecanismos utilizados é o [Observer Pattern do GOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

---

> Só funciona entre agentes locais ou um deles pode ser remoto? É por causa da internet?

Parte da premissa da programação reativa é decompor um problema em passos pequenos que podem ser executados de forma assíncrona e não bloqueante. Esse problema pode estar dividido entre agentes locais e remotos.

A Internet pode ser considerada como um fator que leve à adoção da programação reativa, já que a consulta a sistemas remotos é uma operação bloqueante que pode afetar a escalabilidade do seu sistema.

---

> Aparentemente tem que ter robustez para ser classificada assim?
>   Precisa rodar em vários servidores? Ou é uma opção?

Não. A programação reativa está em alta no mundo dos aplicativos Android, por exemplo. Muitos desenvolvedores estão adotando este paradigma pelas facilidades que ela acaba trazendo e também pelas características da plataforma.

---

> É um paradigma? É um framework? Posso usar em .NET?

É um paradigma. E existem bibliotecas e *toolkits* que implementam esse paradigma. Um exemplo para .NET são as [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx).

Comment: Lendo a resposta eu tive a impressão que ser reativo é aplicar o padrão Observer, é isso mesmo? Será que não é mais complexo que isso?

Comment: Repare que afirmei que o padrão observer é _um_ dos mecanismos utilizados. O [ReactiveManifesto](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) lista diversas características que as aplicações devem ter para ser consideradas reativas. As ReactiveExtensions, por exemplo, extendem o padrão Observer e adicionam a possibilidade de sinalizar erros e o término de streams.

Comment: @LeonardoLima, legal sua resposta, seu comentário fala sobre sinalizar erros, mas sinalizar erros as programações atuais já fazem isso, um dos pilares da programação reativa trabalha sobre isso que é a Resiliente, não vejo nada abordando sobre isso na sua resposta.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza não incluí na minha resposta porque ela foi uma enumeração direta aos questionamentos da pergunta original (e o link indicado originalmente já toca no assunto). O comentário foi um esclarecimento sobre um mal-entendido, exemplificando com uma característica da biblioteca citada.

Answer (score 18):

<sub>A resposta foi elaborada sem focar muito nos pilares da programação reactiva, deixei uma secção dedicada para explicar como cada um dos pilares se mapeia a cada um dos pontos da minha resposta</sub>

## Definição de reativo

Antes de explicar o que é programação reativa creio que vale a pena explicar qual é o significado de reativo [na infopedia](https://www.dicio.com.br/reativo/)

> Que reage.

Ou seja, algo que acontece em consequência de um acontecimento/evento anterior

## Programação reativa

Se o conceito de programação reativa existe, então também existe o conceito de programação não reativa. Vou demonstrar os dois com o seguinte código:

```js
//Programção não reativa

console.log(prompt('Introduza um texto'));

//programação reactiva

function userInput(msg, action){
  action(prompt(msg));
}

userInput('Introduza um texto', console.log);
```

Existe um diferença subtil nos excertos de código. O primeiro pode ser descrito da seguinte forma:

> Abre uma janela para o utilizador introduzir texto O utilizador
>   introduz texto O texto que o utilizador introduziu é escrito na consola

Enquanto o segundo pode ser descrito da seguinte forma

> **Quando** o utilizador escrever o texto na janela, escreva o texto na consola

Com este exemplo você chega á conclusão que sempre que usa callbacks você está a programar reativamente.

Você não tem mais uma linha de fluxo de instruções continua no seu código. Em vez disso você vai usar e abusar dos callbacks para estabelecer **o que acontece quando determinada operação for concluída**.

#### Programação reativa com eventos

Se alguma vez já trabalhou com *user interface* então é quase certo que você já tenha usado programação reativa.

Por exemplo, quando você adiciona um *handler* para um evento de um botão você  está a estipular o que acontece **quando** o utilizador clica no botão.

Este é um exemplo particular do uso de *callbacks* discutido anteriormente.

Aliás esta prática é tão conhecida que existe um paradigma próprio para esta forma de programar. Ela é conhecida como [Programação orientada a eventos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_eventos)

#### Programação reativa e operações de longa duração

Outro sitio onde é comum ver o uso de programação reativa é em operações de longa duração, especialmente se estas tiverem um interface [assíncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124283/). Um dos mais conhecidos entre programadores são os [pedidos AJAX.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116153/)

Deixo aqui um exemplo semelhante a uma das perguntas referidas.

```js
var now = performance.now();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onreadystatechange = function A() {
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    console.log("API SE " + ~~(performance.now() - now) + "ms");
  }
}

request.open('GET', 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow', true);
request.send();
```

Mais uma vez aparecem os *callbacks*, você especifica qual o código que quer executar quando o pedido for satisfeito pelo servidor e a resposta chegar ao seu programa.

#### Programação reativa TUDO EM 1

Se você chegou até aqui deve estar pensando que afinal de contas já programou reativamete e sim praticamente todos nós já o fizemos.

A novidade agora está nas frameworks que lhe tentam proporcionar APIs genéricas para programar reativamente. Mais em particular a framework [Reactive](http://reactivex.io/), disponível [em várias plataformas](http://reactivex.io/languages.html)

Esta framework juntas 3 funcionalidades numa única API.

- Eventos
- Dados
- Processamento assíncrono e ou paralelo

Se me é permitido eu gostava de fazer um paralelo á linguagem `C#` e plataforma `.NET`. Básicamente a framework junta eventos com `Task` e com o `IEnumerable` com os respetivos métodos `Linq` e mais uns extra.

Em particular esta framework tem um cuidado especial no que toca ao tratamento de eventos. Mesmo com um número reduzido de eventos é possível você necessitar de diversas formas de os processar, nomeadamente em relação á ordem dos eventos e á eventual possibilidade de existência de falhas.

A API fornece-lhe já um conjunto bastante satisfatório de possibilidades mas haverá casos onde você deverá ter um cuidado extra para saber se realmente os eventos estão a acontecer na ordem que você deseja, pelo menos foi essa a minha experiência. Você pode dar uma olhada nos [diagramas da framework,](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#transforming) deixo aqui um:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostava de deixar aqui dois exemplos de utilização desta framework em `C#` que já me foram úteis em ambiente profissional e são relativamente simples de entender.

**Observador de ficheiros numa diretoria**

```cs
public IObservable<FileSystemEventArgs> Watch(string path, bool includeExistingFiles = false)
{
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path, "*.*");
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;


    var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern(watcher, "Created")
        .Merge(Observable.FromEventPattern(watcher, "Deleted"))
        .Merge(Observable.FromEventPattern(watcher, "Changed"))
        .Merge(Observable.FromEventPattern(watcher, "Renamed"))
        .Select(a => a.EventArgs as FileSystemEventArgs);
    if (includeExistingFiles)
    {
        var currentFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(f => new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, Path.GetDirectoryName(f), Path.GetFileName(f)));
        observable = observable.Merge(currentFiles.ToObservable());
    }
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    return observable;
}
```

**Executando um processo e retornando um observable**

```cs
public IObservable<EventArgs> ExecuteProcess(string path, string parameters)
{
    var process = new Process() {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, parameters)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        },
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };
    var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern(process, "Exited")
        .Select(a => (EventArgs)a.EventArgs);

    process.Start();
    return observable;
}
```

#### Programação reativa conclusão.

Eu não sei onde o [@Yonathan foi buscar os pilares da programação reactiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55380/35970), mas não obstante parecem-me ser totalmente válidos:

> - **Elástico**: Reage à demanda/carga: aplicações podem fazer uso de    múltiplos núcleos e múltiplos servidores;
> - **Resiliente**: Reage às falhas; aplicações reagem e se recuperam de       falhas de software, hardware e de conectividade;
> - **Message Driven:** Reage aos eventos (*event driven*): em vez de compor       aplicações por múltiplas *threads* síncronas, sistemas
>     são compostos de     gerenciadores de eventos assíncronos e não
>     bloqueantes;
> - **Responsivo**: Reage aos usuários: aplicações que oferecem interações       ricas e “tempo real” com usuários.

Se acompanhou a resposta até agora sabe que tudo isso é verdade.

É *message driven* porque você diz **quando** fazer.

É *responsivo* porque só faz a operação está completa (não bloqueia)

É resilitente. Pelo menos o Reactive tem uma extensao, que lhe permite tentar executar determanido evento um número de vezes.

É elástico. Pelo menos na framework .net decide por voce quantas threads a framework deverá usar.

#### Respondendo a outras perguntas suas

> É um paradigma?

A [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) diz que sim, ênfase meu.

> In computing, reactive programming is an asynchronous **programming
>   paradigm**

Gostava só de adicionar que para além do programação orientada a eventos já mencionada por mim, a programação reativa traz elementos novos suficientes para ser considerado um paradigma diferente. Lembre-se das tres funcionalidades que mencionei: **Eventos**, **Dados**, **Processamento assíncrono e ou paralelo**

> Só funciona entre agentes locais ou um deles pode ser remoto? É por
>   causa da internet?

Não é por causa da *internet* mas sim porque alguém determinou que havia um problema para resolver. Que eu saiba não havia nada até agora que lhe permitisse juntar estas três funcionalidades duma forma elegante e fácil de manusear.

> Aparentemente tem que ter robustez para ser classificada assim?
>   Precisa rodar em vários servidores? Ou é uma opção?

Se prestou atenção á minha resposta eu não dei muito atenção a robustez e muito menos falei em vários servidores.

Apenas mencionei que pode ser possível, com a framework reactive, tentar executar determinada operação novamente, se ela falhar.

A programação reativa pode ou no ser usada em ambientes distribuídos, a robustez vai depender de como o seu sistema distribuído estiver implementado bem como todos os serviços que participam nele.

Comment: Ainda quero reler, mas já vi que está muito bom, parece ter dado para entender tudo.

Comment: Só me encontrei no assunto do meio da sua resposta para frente, seu primeiro exemplo exemplo pra mim não demostra programação reativa apenas um novo fluxo a ser seguido e não a possibilidade de uma outra decisão ( siga isso caso não der certo) *Não vi todas as resposta que a pergunta faz*. Do meio para o fim achei legal.

Comment: aqui esta as referencias usadas na outra pergunta http://blog.andrefaria.com/programacao-reativa-reactive-programming

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4zRhjSto8U&t=27

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Algumas perguntas foram respondidas no conteúdo e nao necessitavam de ser respondidas novamente. Aliás só nao respondi 2 perguntas mesmo: `Onde deve ser usada?` e `Qual é o mecanismo concreto usado para isto funcionar?` (embora tenha falado no reactive extensions). Como disse na minha resposta a programacao reativa consiste bastante em especificar em `quando` fazer, embora possa nao ser programacao reativa foi o mais simples que encontrei para ilustrar o que quiz dizer.